# When is $_FILES created/cleared | Relationship to javascript reloads

Tags: php, javascript

I use this line

```
isset( $_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'] );
```

to test for a file upload.  The issue I'm having is that I can't get the value to "clear".

If I go in and manually type

```
unset( $_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'] );
```

I can clear it but once I remove it, it is somehow populated by PHP.  There are not actual file uploads in this process.

How can I accurately detect when a file has been uploaded and when the upload script is done.

The reason I ask is because Control Class works off this variable and it recently stopped working.

In javascript I recently changed the way I do reloads and I think this is causing a persistence issue with my PHP variables.

Particularly I went from window.location.href = location....to window.reload()

```
<?php 

include 'class.Control.php';

$ControlEntryObject = new ControlEntry();

    class ControlEntry
    {
        public function __construct()  
        {   
            if( isset( $_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'] ) )
            {
                if( ( $_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name']) != '' )
                    {
                    Control::upload( $_FILES['ufile']['type'], $_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'] );
                    }
                else
                    {
                    Control::reload();
                    }
            }
            else if( isset($_POST['ajax_type']) )
            {
                Control::ajax( $_POST['ajax_type'] );
            }
            else
            {
               Control::reload();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking the temp file name, you're better of checking the error code to see if an upload was successful.

```
if( $_FILES['ufile']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK )
{
    // process upload
}
```

That way your script can safely handle get and post requests.